# Not able to extract string using multiple special characters or pattern in python simultaneously

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I have a dataset where I am trying to extract the simple town name from the longer messy version shown here. Most of them are followed by parentheses " (.*", but some do not follow this pattern and end in ":" (see line 200). Finally, there are some that do not have parentheses but split parts with a comma "," (see line 240, 246).

```
                                             'Region'
196    Boston (Boston University, Boston College, Bos...
197           Bridgewater (Bridgewater State College)[2]
198    Cambridge (Harvard University, Massachusetts I...
199                       Chestnut Hill (Boston College)
200                The Colleges of Worcester Consortium:
201                             Dudley (Nichols College)
240                     Faribault, South Central College
241    Mankato (Minnesota State University, Mankato),...
242    Marshall (Southwest Minnesota State University...
243    Moorhead (Minnesota State University, Moorhead...
244           Morris (University of Minnesota Morris)[2]
245    Northfield (Carleton College, St. Olaf College...
246                 North Mankato, South Central College
247    St. Cloud (St. Cloud State University, The Col...
248            St. Joseph (College of Saint Benedict)[2]
249             St. Peter (Gustavus Adolphus College)[2]
```

What I would ideally like to see is:

```
                                   'RegionName'
    196                                 Boston
    197                            Bridgewater
    198                              Cambridge
    199                          Chestnut Hill
    200   The Colleges of Worcester Consortium
    201                                 Dudley
    240                              Faribault
    241                                Mankato
    242                               Marshall
    243                               Moorhead
    244                                 Morris
    245                             Northfield
    246                          North Mankato
    247                              St. Cloud
    248                             St. Joseph
    249                              St. Peter
```

My code currently is:

```
df['RegionName'] = df['Region'].str.extract('(.*)[:(,]', expand=False)
```

But this gives me the weird result of not getting the parentheses right:

```
196    Boston (Boston University, Boston College, Bos...
197                                         Bridgewater 
198    Cambridge (Harvard University, Massachusetts I...
199                                       Chestnut Hill 
200                 The Colleges of Worcester Consortium
201                                              Dudley 
240                                         Faribault
241     Mankato (Minnesota State University, Mankato)
242                                         Marshall 
243    Moorhead (Minnesota State University, Moorhead
244                                           Morris 
245                      Northfield (Carleton College
246                                     North Mankato
247             St. Cloud (St. Cloud State University
248                                       St. Joseph 
249                                        St. Peter
```

I have also tried:

```
df['RegionName'] = df['Region'].str.extract('(.*)[ (.*|:|,]', expand=False)
```

I am not sure exactly how to extract the string using all three patterns at the same time. Would be open to a two line solution as well.
Thanks (apologies if this is formatted poorly!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just extract any 0 or more chars other than `:`, `,` or `(` at the beginning of a string with

```
df['RegionName'] = df['Region'].str.extract(r'^([^:(,]*)\b', expand=False)
```

If you are working with Python 2.x, use `(?u)` at the beginning of the pattern so that the word boundary `\b` could also match the right places in a Unicode string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `([^:(,]*)` - Group 1: zero or more (`*`) consecutive occurrences of any char other than (the `[^...]` forms a *negated* character class) `:`, `(` and `,`.
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXdYG4/1) and a Python 3 demo below:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> item_list = ['Boston (Boston University, Boston College, Bos...','Bridgewater (Bridgewater State College)[2]','Cambridge (Harvard University, Massachusetts I...','Chestnut Hill (Boston College)','The Colleges of Worcester Consortium:','Dudley (Nichols College)','Faribault, South Central College','Mankato (Minnesota State University, Mankato),...','Marshall (Southwest Minnesota State University...','Moorhead (Minnesota State University, Moorhead...','Morris (University of Minnesota Morris)[2]','Northfield (Carleton College, St. Olaf College...','North Mankato, South Central College','St. Cloud (St. Cloud State University, The Col...','St. Joseph (College of Saint Benedict)[2]','St. Peter (Gustavus Adolphus College)[2]']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(item_list, columns=['Region'])
>>> df['RegionName'] = df['Region'].str.extract(r'^([^:(,]*)\b', expand=False)
>>> df['RegionName']

                              RegionName  
0                                 Boston  
1                            Bridgewater  
2                              Cambridge  
3                          Chestnut Hill  
4   The Colleges of Worcester Consortium  
5                                 Dudley  
6                              Faribault  
7                                Mankato  
8                               Marshall  
9                               Moorhead  
10                                Morris  
11                            Northfield  
12                         North Mankato  
13                             St. Cloud  
14                            St. Joseph  
15                             St. Peter  
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Something I didn't show in the dataset is that there are states listed such as "Michigan\[edit\]", which I want to delete. Previously the `str.extract` made these into NaN's and so I would dropna these. But your method leaves them in the dataset (they become "Michigan[edit"). How would you adjust for this?

Part 2: 
I tried: 
`df['RegionName'] = df['RegionName'].str.replace(r'(^.*\[edit$)', np.nan)`
which turned everything into NaN's. Why would that be? Instead I replaced it with an empty cell, then replaced empty to NaN. Seems inefficient though. Thx

Comment: Try [`r'^([^:(,]*?)\s*[:(,]'`](https://regex101.com/r/asdHNp/1) and use your previous `dropna` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have three possible delimiters, you can take advantage of chained split(), since split will return the unmodified string if the delimiter is not found.

```
>>> s = """196    Boston (Boston University, Boston College, Bos...
... 197           Bridgewater (Bridgewater State College)[2]
... 198    Cambridge (Harvard University, Massachusetts I...
... 199                       Chestnut Hill (Boston College)
... 200                The Colleges of Worcester Consortium:
... 201                             Dudley (Nichols College)
... 240                     Faribault, South Central College
... 241    Mankato (Minnesota State University, Mankato),...
... 242    Marshall (Southwest Minnesota State University...
... 243    Moorhead (Minnesota State University, Moorhead...
... 244           Morris (University of Minnesota Morris)[2]
... 245    Northfield (Carleton College, St. Olaf College...
... 246                 North Mankato, South Central College
... 247    St. Cloud (St. Cloud State University, The Col...
... 248            St. Joseph (College of Saint Benedict)[2]
... 249             St. Peter (Gustavus Adolphus College)[2]"""
>>> for i in s.split('\n'):
...    number, text = i.split('(')[0].split(',')[0].split(':')[0].split(' ',1)
...    print('{} {}'.format(number, text.strip()))
...
196 Boston
197 Bridgewater
198 Cambridge
199 Chestnut Hill
200 The Colleges of Worcester Consortium
201 Dudley
240 Faribault
241 Mankato
242 Marshall
243 Moorhead
244 Morris
245 Northfield
246 North Mankato
247 St. Cloud
248 St. Joseph
249 St. Peter
```

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to do the same transformation for your strings.

Comment: I don't think the line number and padding is part of the data - it's just how the data is formatted when printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
([\w\s.]+)(?<!\s)
```

You can remove the negative look-behind `(?<!\s)` at the end if you don't care about trailing white spaces.